# How to call an exception with post method (AJAX)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, exception, post

If the post method is unsuccessful I want to throw an exception and write to an error log? Basically if this method returns no results I want to throw an exception and write to file.

Post method:

```
$.post("ip.php", function( data ){
$("#ip").val(data.ip);
$("#country").val(data.country);
$('#campaignID').val(data.campaignID);
}, "json");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the part of the question:

> If the post method is unsuccessful I want to throw an exception (...)

You could chain a [`.fail()` callback](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.fail/) method to the `$.post()` request as mentioned by [*@Grimbode*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29086976/962734)

Or use [**`$.ajax()`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead, where is an `error` option - function to be called if the request fails.
The `$.ajax()` equivalent to your `$.post()` method would be:

```
$.ajax({
    type     : "POST",
    url      : "ip.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(data){
        $("#ip").val(data.ip);
        $("#country").val(data.country);
        $('#campaignID').val(data.campaignID);
    },
    error   : function(jqXHR/*object*/, textStatus/*string*/, errorThrown/*object*/){
        // throw an error ...
        // console.log('Type of error: ' + textStatus);
    },
});
```

As for that part:

> (...) write to an error log

It's not possible to write any file with javascript. Since it's a [client side scripting language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_scripting) that executes in a client browser, it has no access to the server. Well, that's how it works.

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very complete!

Answer (score 1):

Just add the *fail();* method.

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
  alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
  alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  alert( "finished" );
});
```